# What is the best data structure to use for this?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have to store a list of 3 values A,B and C. A and B are a pair of values.
C contains two values that describe what the record is, let's just say 1 and 2.

For my purpose, I will be constantly looking up A and/or B to see whether a value exists or the pair exists.

C is only used at the end of the processing to split it into two lists.

Further explaining what the data means -> 
A and B are just IDs and C is an action like Merge and Demerge. 
So it looks like this:

1, 2, Merge

3, 4, Demerge

I have a bunch of rules that require me to look up whether the next A or B exist in 'any' IDs, or whether A and B are a pair in a record

Would it be better to use a 
    `List<Tuple<A,B,C>> or Dictionary<Tuple<A,B>,C>`

Thanks

Comment: You use list when you need to loop over the list to count, do something with each element. You use Dictionary when you want to get the element by the key, no need to loop. Key like the pointer, point to exactly the element. Think what is exactly your pupose and decide to use list or dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? Any reason you aren't using something else, like a class?

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between A and B? Could you have `Dictionary<A, Dictionary<B, C>>`?

Comment: you have to tell us much more about the kind of data we are looking at - if you only want to *remember* 3 values (why has `A` and `B` to be a pair?) then just use 3 fields/properties on some class...

Comment: Thanks, I've added some more details on what my data is meant to be. The values of A and B are just Ids, so simple strings, but I need to keep them separate and also as a pair as they relate to each other. At the same time, during my processing, I need to look up these values all the time - whether they exist or whether they exist as a pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a DataTable which worked perfectly to access any number of columns I needed and also for updating, deleting etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a `Dictionary` seems to suit you better. As you said, you do not care about the `C` value until afterwards, nor is it part of your unique key. A dictionary will force you to only have a single entry for any given `Tuple<A,B>` which it seems like you prefer (because you're only checking if a value or tuple already exists). A `List` would allow you to have duplicate entries.

Depending on your requirements, perhaps you can create a class to represent this object better (to avoid the additional overhead from `Dictionary`, as you seem to be using a minor subset of its features). For example, do you need to iterate over each `Tuple`?